# A queueing system for Perl

Tags: perl, task-queue

I'm working on a Perl project which needs a FIFO message queue for distributing tasks between several processes on a single machine (UNIX). The queue size may grow up to 1M jobs.

I've tried [`IPC::DirQueue`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aDirQueue), but it becomes awfully slow with 50k or so jobs enqueued. What are good alternatives to this module which can be used in Perl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had pretty good success with using ZeroMQ for this sort of problem, both with Perl and other languages.

In my experience, the [ZeroMQ](http://metacpan.org/module/ZeroMQ) module appears to be the most reliable binding for Perl currently.

Comment: ZeroMQ looks very interesting, I'll try it.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it under the conditions you list, but [Thread::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread%3a%3aQueue) has proven useful to me. Combined with [forks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?forks), it can be used to communicate with processes, as long as those processes were spawned by the queue creator.

```
use forks;  # If you want to use processes instead of threads.
use Thread::Queue qw( );
```

A worker model is usually ideal.

```
my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @workers;
for (1..$NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (my $item = $q->dequeue()) {
         ...
      }
   };
}

# ... Enqueue requests [ $q->enqueue($request); ] ...

# Signal termination
$q->enqueue(undef) for 1..@workers;

# Collect workers.
$_->join() for @workers;
```